# Making a typealias with a protocol

Tags: ios, swift3, protocols, type-alias

Can I define 2 typealias like this?

```
typealias MyViewControllerTypeOne = UIViewController

typealias MyViewControllerTypeTwo = UIViewController, MyGreatProtocol
```

I already know that the second one does not work with this syntax.

But what is the way to get the result I want?
(I presume what I want is pretty obvious here.)

Answer (score 4):

In `Swift 4` you can now compose a class with any number of protocols by using the `&` operator:

```
typealias MyViewControllerTypeTwo = UIViewController & MyGreatProtocol
```

Check the [WWDC 2017 "What's New in Swift"](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/402/) around 05:23.

You can also see the section "Protocol Composition" in the [Swift 4.0 documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html), although it doesn't mention composing classes with protocols.

Comment: I see. I had tried this in Swift 3. It didn't worked. At least this is a good news for Swift 4.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as a tuple -

```
typealias tupleAlias = (viewController :UIViewController,protocol: MyGreatProtocol)
```

***EDIT:***
example use-

```
typealias PersonTuple = (name: String, address: String)

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let tupleInstance = getPerson(for: "Jack")
        print(tupleInstance.address)//Prints India
    }
    func getPerson(for name: String) -> PersonTuple {
        return (name, "India")
    }
```

Comment: This typealias definition seems to work, but how do you use it later to define an object of type tupleAlias? If try to use it like on would use UIViewController it doesn't work.

Comment: @Michel i have edited answer, it's depends how you are using it.